# How to Implement Ethereum Wallet Address Validation in SwiftUI Using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ethereum

I'm new to the Swift programming language. I'm developing an iOS app using SwiftUI and Swift, and I need assistance implementing Ethereum wallet address validation. I want to create a custom TextField that checks whether a user-entered Ethereum address is valid.

```
struct OtherOptionView: View {


@State var enterdWalletAddress: String = ""
@State private var isValidAddress = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        Text("Connect your wallet").font(.custom(CustomFont.Inter.semiBold, size: 20)).padding(.horizontal).padding(.vertical)
        
        TextField("Enter your wallet address", text: $enterdWalletAddress)
            .padding()
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.6), lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .font(.body).padding(.horizontal).padding(.vertical)
        
        //MARK: cancel button
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            Button(action: {
                //action
            }, label: {
                Text("Cancel")
                    .font(.custom(CustomFont.Inter.semiBold, size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .frame(width: 150)
                    .overlay(
                        Capsule()
                            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                
            })
            
            //MARK: connect button
            Button(action: {
                //action
            }, label: {
                Text("Connect")
                    .font(.custom(CustomFont.Inter.semiBold, size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .frame(width: 150)
                    .background(
                        Color.blue
                            .cornerRadius(40)
                    )
            })
        }.frame(width: 350, alignment: .center).padding(.bottom, 30)
        
    }.frame(width: 350, height: 350).background(Color.white).cornerRadius(15)
}

func walletValid() {
        
    }

}
```

The code above is a simplified version of my app's interface. I'm looking for guidance on how to implement Ethereum wallet address validation in the `walletValid` function and update the `isValidAddress` variable accordingly.

Currently, I'm struggling with validating the address format and updating the UI to display validation results correctly. Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this validation in SwiftUI using Swift code? Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated.